is scaling necessary for logistic regression?
I'm trying to run a logistic regression algorithm from SKlearn in order to identify some particles and when I rescale the data before the training the model is simply incapable of selecting any of my particles, however if I don't it has an efficiency of 70% in identifying my particles without the need for a big C-value. is the scaling needed?

Welcome to CV.  Scaling s usually done to improve interpretation of model  coefficients or help with computation.  Strictly speaking it's not required.   One pitfall could be Scaling training and test data separately.  Scaling might need to be done before the train-test split.

@NBrouwer - I thought best practice if you scale was to scale the training data, and then later apply that scaling to the test data (as if you started with just the training data, built your final model, and then applied it to new unseen test data).

@henry yes you're right.  My comment doesn't reflect what should be done in practice ("pitfall" is poor word choice.)  Im hypothesizing that an issue with the split could result in what the OP is seeing, but upon reflection it would have to be pretty unbalanced
